# gnu screen automation

Tags: shell, automation, gnu-screen, script

i'd like to launch GNU screen, some shell command in it, then open new screen window(s) with different command(s) - all that automatically, from a script. is it possible?

#### UPDATE

the screen windows should not be closed after executing the commands, i just want to have the screen session preserved (and detached)

Answer (score 5):

You can put your commands in a file, e.g., `myscreenrc`, like this:

```
screen command1
screen command2
screen command3
```

and then execute `screen` with the `-c` option followed by the name of that file, e.g.,

```
screen -c myscreenrc
```

UPDATE

in reponse to the updated question. The commands I used for testing were `screen vim foo` and `screen vim bar`, so I didn't see the screen-closing problem.  The following solves the screen-closing problem, but it seems a bit of a kludge.

```
screen bash -c 'ls foo; exec bash -i'
screen bash -c 'ls bar; exec bash -i'
```

`ls` was just a convenient command for testing this problem.

UPDATE #2

Another approach would be to start the command from the shell's rc file rather than from screen's rc file. It requires another file for each command, though. For example, to run `top` in a `screen` window such that quitting `top` will return you to a `bash` prompt in that same window, create a file, call it `runtop`, that contains the following:

```
. ~/.bashrc
top
```

Then put this line in the file we're calling `screenrc`:

```
screen bash --rcfile ~/runtop -i
```

and start `screen` as

```
screen -c screenrc
```

Comment: interesting, it does the job and quits, but i need the screen windows to stay.. maybe i should make my question more clear

Comment: good work, but it's not ideal, if i launch bash with some command, i'd like the shell to not quit, not run the new shell. for interactive tasks, e.g. `bash -i -c top` it's usable, unfortunately, shell quits immediately after quitting the top.

Comment: @mykhal: See if UPDATE #2 to my answer helps.